# Put elements of a list into accessor in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have a vector with some data, and a list of vectors whose elements represent indices in that vector.

```
v <- c("A","B","C","D")
l <- list(c(3,2,1),c(4,1))
```

I would like to convert the list according to the vector. So, what I want is

```
[[1]]
[1] "C" "B" "A"

[[2]]
[1] "D" "A"
```

Of course, I can do this:

```
access <- function(x, vec) {
  return (vec[x])
}
lapply(l, access, vec = v)
```

And this gives me the result I wanted. Nevertheless, I feel there must be some less awkward way of doing something so simple, perhaps using the "[" function. I tried this:

```
lapply(l, "[", v)
```

It seems like this does the reverse of what I want, i.e. it uses the elements of v as the index to access elements of the list. So it tries to do something like

```
l[[i]]["A","B","C","D"]
```

Which is obviously not what I want. So, is there a way to use "[" or some other function to access a vector using the elements of a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function on the fly

```
lapply(l, function(x) v[x])
```

---

With `purrr`, the anonymous call can be more compact

```
library(purrr)
map(l, ~ v[.x])
```